# Control the range with show_hist of rasterio

Tags: rasterio, matplotlib

When I set up the "range" argument, Running this code will have an Error.
Would help me with how to set up the range ?

```
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
a =src.read(1)
show_hist(a, bins=100,histtype='stepfilled',lw=0.0, stacked=False, range =[1000,4000])

TypeError: matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes.hist() got multiple values for keyword argument 'range'
```

Comment: You can't. `rasterio.plot.show_hist` [computes the min/max](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/rasterio/plot.py#L266), then [passes that as the range arg](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/rasterio/plot.py#L308) to `matplotlib` and you can't override that. Suggest you raise an enhancement request that any `kwargs` passed in to `show_hist` override any that rasterio might set internally. Alternatively, you can just make a copy of [`show_hist`](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/rasterio/plot.py#L231-L317) in your code and modify that.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will do both.